# How to get "Suggested sites to follow","Suggested docs to follow" by programming?

Tags: 2013, recommendations

SharePoint 2013 provides recommendation features on relevant people, sites and documents to follow. How to get the recommendations by programming and so that they could be used in customized SharePoint apps or webparts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use WebPartManager to get the webpart via powershell and try to export and reuse in other page. 
You can give it a try. I have not tested myself.